# How to use pick_asset from the photos module?

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, photo

I use the App Python Offline.

I tried to use photos module.

```
import photos
assets = photos.pick_asset(title='Pick some assets', multi=True)
print(assets)
```

I got this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pick_asset'

https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/python-offline/id1351388468?mt=8

http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/photos.html

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct module "photos" installed? Try using the help or dir method on that photos  --- help(photos), and check if the method exists in that scope

Comment: the result of help() is None, the result of dir() is only showing generic double underscore builtins

Comment: Then the module is probably not installed correctly. You should check the manual for that App Python Offline and see how to install modules.

Answer (score 0):

`AttributeError` for pythonista means the attribute does not exist. As this is not a PC platform I am not sure if you can debug it in pythonista in itself. As I see in the docs it the attribute `photos.pick_asset` is present.

You can try uninstalling the app and reinstalling it again. Similar case happened with me in case of `matplotlib`, I reinstalled and it worked again.